# How can I avoid a Stack Overflow using this Evaluation (BFS)

Tags: java, regex

I have an NFA that I have constructed and I'm running this method to evaluate the machine to see if an expression is valid.  This works for small regular expressions, but when the size of my regular expression and thusly the size of my NFA become too large, this search throws a stack overflow at me.  I'm fairly certain it's because I've implemented a BFS, am using recursion, and am probably not handling my base cases very well.

This method takes an expression and a node (beginning with the start node of an NFA).  First it checks if the length of the expression is zero, and if I'm in an accept node (a boolean value on the node), then I return true.
If the expression length is zero but the current node is not an accept node I return false.

If neither of these evaluate, then I get a list of all the nodes that the current node can reach using a "e" (epsilon) transition, and evaluate them.

If there are no "e" nodes, then I remove the first character from an input expression, make a shortened substring of the expression (removing the front of the expression), then look for a list of nodes that that node can reach using the removed character and the reduced expression.

If neither of these hit, then I return false

A basic Regular Expression is (a|b)*a
and an example of a evaluation expression would be aaaa
Which gets reduced at each pass, aaaa->aaa->aa->a->

```
    private boolean evaluate(autoNode node, String expression)
{

    if(expression.length()==0 && node.getAccept())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(expression.length()==0 && !node.getAccept())
    {
        return false;
    }

    String evalExp = expression.charAt(0)+""; //The first character in the expression
    String redExp = expression.substring(1, expression.length()); 

    //for each epsilon transition, evaluate it
    if(node.getTransSet().contains("e"))
    {
        //if this node has an "e" transition then...
        ArrayList<autoNode> EpsilonTransMap = node.getPathMap("e");
        //The above ArrayList is a list of all the nodes that this node can reach
        //using the "e" / epsilon transition
        for(autoNode nodes : EpsilonTransMap)
        {               
            if(evaluate(nodes, expression))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    //for each transition on that key evaluate it
    if(node.getTransSet().contains(evalExp))
    {
        //if this node has a transition from the front of the expression then...
        ArrayList<autoNode> TransitionKeyMap = node.getPathMap(evalExp);
        //The above ArrayList is a list of all the nodes that this node can reach
        //on a transition equal to the "key" removed from the front of the expression String
        for(autoNode nodes : TransitionKeyMap)
        {
            if(evaluate(nodes, redExp))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm aware that I've probably caused my own problem by using bfs searching instead of dfs.  I'm wondering if someone can help me fix this and avoid a stack overflow by having too many things going on at once.  Because while (a|b)*a can evaluate just fine...

((aa)+|(bb)+|(cc)+)(ba)*(ca)*

creates a rather large NFA, that causes a stack overflow on evaluating just:
"a"

Anything that doesn't result in me scrapping the method entirely would be great and appreciated.

Comment: Maybe, you can try convert NFA to DFA , to reduce backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't actually have a DFS *or* a BFS in here, but that's not important.  I guess it's also not important that you can't use regular expressions with the letter "e" in them.

What is important is that you're getting stack overflows whenever you reach a cycle of epsilon transitions.  For example:

evaluate(n1,"aa") finds an epsilon transition from n1 to n2, and recurses:

evaluate(n2,"aa") which finds an epsilon transition from n2 to n1 and recurses:

evaluate(n1,"aa") .. and so on, recursing until the stack overflows.

There are a bunch of ways you could fix this...  But even if you fix it this is still a pretty bad algorithm for evaluating NFAs -- it can take exponential time in the number of states!

EDIT -- so, here's the right way to do NFA evaluation, in pseudo code:

```
boolean evaluate(Node nfa, String str)
{
    Set<Node> fromStates = new Set();
    fromStates.add(nfa);
    closeEpsilons(fromStates);

    for (char chr in str)
    {
        if (fromStates.size()==0)
            return false;

        //find all the states we can get to from
        //fromStates via chr

        Set<Node> toStates = new Set();
        for (Node fromState in fromStates)
        {
            //OP's code would say .getPathMap(chr) here
            for(Node toState in fromState.getTransitionTargets(chr))
            {
                if (!toStates.contains(toState))
                    toStates.add(toState);
            }
        }
        closeEpsilons(toStates);

        //process the rest of the string with the state set we just found
        fromStates = toStates;
    }

    //string is done.  see if anything accepts
    for(Node state in fromStates)
    {
        if (state.accepts())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//expand a state set with all states is reaches via epsilons
void closeEpsilons(Set<Node> states)
{
    Queue<Node> processQueue = new Queue();
    processQueue.addAll(states);

    while(!processQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        Node fromState = processQueue.removeFirst();

        //OP's code would say "getPathMap("e") here
        for(Node toState in fromState.getEpsilonTargets())
        {
            if (!states.contains(toState))
            {
                //found a new state
                states.add(toState);
                //we'll have to search it for epsilons
                processQueue.add(toState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this working, and after having spent so much time writing a bum method it's nice to see a cleaner approach.  

I obviously still have a lot to learn, which makes me nervous, yeesh.  This solves the stack overflow problem which helps, I still have some issues evaluating, but I think that's from my NFA construction so I need to take a closer look, but this is hugely helpful, especially after spending banging my head against a wall.

Thanks again!

Comment: I have an open source project that does NFA construction and DFA building, if you want to look at some real-life code for it: http://mtimmerm.github.io/dfalex/